# Why come card content is not showing in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  Button,
  CardMedia,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import ThumbUpAlt from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpAlt";
import Delete from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import MoreHoriz from "@mui/icons-material/MoreHoriz";
import moment from "moment";

import useStyles from "./styles";

const Post = ({ post }) => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={post.selectedFile}
        title={post.title}
      >
        <div className={classes.overlay}>
          <Typography variant="h6">{post.creator}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2">
            {moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}
          </Typography>
        </div>

// till here the card is showing

        <div className={classes.overlay2}>
          <Button style={{ color: "white" }} size="small" onClick={() => {}}>
            <MoreHoriz fontSize="default" />
          </Button>
        </div>

        <div className={classes.details}>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
            {post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag}`)}
          </Typography>
        </div>

        <CardContent>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h5" gutterBottom>
            {post.message}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>

        <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
          <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {}}>
            <ThumbUpAlt fontSize="small" />
            Like
            {post.likeCount}
          </Button>

          <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {}}>
            <Delete fontSize="small" />
            Delete
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </CardMedia>
    </Card>
  );
};
export default Post;
```

I'm passing data from parent to child as a prop.After this i'm mapping the prop in card.But the issue is card is only showing till  `classes.overlay` afterwards nothing is showing.Also code is not showing in inspect.I don't know what the issue is as i'm new to MUI.

May i know what the issue is so that i can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is because you are wrapping your component inside the CardMedia tags, when it should be a self-closing tag, so your code should look like this:

```
const Post = ({ post }) => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={post.selectedFile}
        title={post.title}
      /> // <--- This is the change
        <div className={classes.overlay}>
          <Typography variant="h6">{post.creator}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2">
            {moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.overlay2}>
          <Button style={{ color: "white" }} size="small" onClick={() => {}}>
            <MoreHoriz fontSize="default" />
          </Button>
        </div>

        <div className={classes.details}>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
            {post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag}`)}
          </Typography>
        </div>

        <CardContent>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h5" gutterBottom>
            {post.message}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>

        <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
          <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {}}>
            <ThumbUpAlt fontSize="small" />
            Like
            {post.likeCount}
          </Button>

          <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {}}>
            <Delete fontSize="small" />
            Delete
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};
export default Post;
```